# How to get a column of group id values for a pandas DataFrame based on the groups produced by a groupby operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame which I want to `groupby` with a few columns. I know how to aggregate the data after that, or view each index tuple. However, I am unsure of the best way to just append the "group number" of each group in a column on the original dataframe:

For example, I have a dataframe, `df`, with two indices (`a_id` and `b_id`) which I want to use for grouping the `df` using `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'a_id':['q','q','q','q','q','r','r','r','r','r'],
                  'b_id':['m','m','j','j','j','g','g','f','f','f'],
                  'val': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8]})

# Output:
  a_id b_id  val
0    q    m    1
1    q    m    2
2    q    j    3
3    q    j    4
4    q    j    5
5    r    g    6
6    r    g    7
7    r    f    8
8    r    f    9
9    r    f    8
```

When I do the groupby, rather than aggregate everything, I just want to add a column `group_id` that has an integer representing the group. However, I am not sure if there is a simple way to do this. My current solution involves inverting the `GroupBy.indices` dictionary, turning that into a series, and appending it to the dataframe as follows:

```
gb = a.groupby(['a_id','b_id'])
dict_g = dict(enumerate(gb.indices.values()))
dict_g_reversed = {x:k for k,v in dict_g.items() for x in v}
group_ids = pd.Series(dict_g_reversed)
a['group_id'] = group_ids
```

This gives me sort of what I want, although the `group_id` indices are not in the right order. This seems like it should be a simple function, but I'm not sure why it seems not to be. I know in MATLAB, for example, they have a [`findgroups`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) that does exactly what I would like. So far I haven't been able to find an equivalent in pandas. How can this be done with a pd DataFrame?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your expected output as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `ngroup` this will provide the order as occurrence

```
a.groupby(['a_id','b_id']).ngroup()
```

Or using `factorize`

```
pd.factorize(list(map(tuple,a[['a_id','b_id']].values.tolist())))[0]+1
df['newid']=pd.factorize(list(map(tuple,a.values.tolist())))[0]+1
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed ngroups. Thanks for pointing it out.